# Adjust MySQL ID column +1

Tags: mysql

I have about 1000 rows, and want to increment all of the rows' ID number by 1. I was thinking something like this might work

`UPDATE table`

`SET id = id+1`

I tried in phpMyAdmin, but got this: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'

This makes perfect sense, but how can I get around it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Isn't it much easier to order it backwards?

```
update table set id = id +1 order by id desc
```

this works for me...

Comment: +1 cool, i didn't know you could use order by on an update statement

Comment: didn't know I could order backwards, this makes sense.. let me try it

Comment: update table set id = id +1     this will also work no matter you add order by or not

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

1. crate a temp table
2. copy all data to this temp table with desired id
3. delete original table
4. At the end rename the temp table to original table.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

use a big enough number that wont create duplicates

```
update table set id = id + 1000001;
update table set id = id - 1000000;
```

keep in mind this will increase the auto increment key if you are using one